# Confused, MySQL select two tables - if one missing, return the other table

Tags: mysql, sql

My code is:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts,test
WHERE accounts.Username = test.Username AND test.Username IN ('BigD')
```

If there is nothing in the test table, I still want to return what is in the accounts table. Currently it only returns information if both tables got some information. How to do that?
Heard if you're using FULL JOIN it's possible, but don't get how to implement it here.

Comment: I suspect you meant `...WHERE accounts.Username = test.Username...`. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts LEFT JOIN test
    ON accounts.Username = test.Username
WHERE test.Username IN ('BigD')
```

Your original query is written using the old ANSI-89 style of join, where the criteria for the join appears in the `WHERE` clause.  In addition to being hard to read, it makes it difficult to figure out how to modify the query to get what you want.

Comment: I posted this answer substantially before Gordon posted his, for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a FULL JOIN, but a OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN test ON accounts.Username= test.Username 
WHERE test.Username IN ('BigD')
```

So you will obtains all rows from "account" and only matching rows from  "test" with  "test.Username IN ('BigD')" !

---

If you want to only get one match in accounts and list all matches in the test, the join can be reversed by :

```
SELECT * FROM accounts 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN test ON accounts.Username= test.Username 
WHERE test.Username IN ('BigD')
```

Note: the "OUTER" keyword is optionnal !

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax moves the condition in the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause, because it is on the second table.

However, you probably want the test on the first table anyway:

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN
     test t
     ON a.Username = t.Username
WHERE a.Username IN ('BigD');
```

If you don't want `username` twice in the result set, then use `USING` instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN
     test t
     USING (username) 
WHERE Username IN ('BigD');
```

Comment: Oh that seems to work. However! If I want to only get one match in accounts and list all matches in the test, how would I do that?                           Like I have one table including name, age and so forth which is Accounts and another one named Test which includes comments. I want to list all comments, but only the single account. Currently it only picks the newest.

Comment: @thojohify . . . Nothing in this answer nor in your question suggests or chooses the "newest".  If you have another question, then ask it as a question and not in a comment; include sample data and desired results.